# Magento 2 assigning Custom User resources in User roles

Tags: magento2, resource-model, user-roles

When I am trying to create a new User role.

After selecting the Custom resource List is Not showing, Can u Please help me how I can do this.
[image]

---

I what to Create a login for Product Manager to Upload Product details.

Answer (score 0):

This bug can come from your custom module. You should disable each custom module and check.